# Can I monkey patch NilClass to return nil for missing methods?

Tags: ruby, null

In other languages like (objective-c for example) calling a method on a nil object fails silently and returns nil but in ruby you get errors like this...

```
undefined method `some_method' for nil:NilClass
```

which (for me) results in code like this:

```
if some_object && some_object.cool?  # instead of if some_object.cool?
  # do some cool stuff
end
```

or

```
some_object.do_awsome_thing if some_object
```

Which all seems backwards and weird.

### Two questions

1. What am I doing wrong, what's the correct way to deal with having the possibility of a nil object
2. What kinds of awful awful things would happen if I just monkey patched the nil object to return nil for missing_methods?

IE:

```
class NilClass
  def missing_method
    nil
  end
end
```

Comment: Migrate to some other stack-exchange site?

Comment: Nay, this is probably getting close-voted for being too subjective (i.e. there's no definitive, objective answer, leading it to be difficult to answer directly and likely to solicit extended debate).

Comment: This is an extremely opinionated question, but the reason why it doesn't happen often is because failing is good. Check out [Failing Fast](http://martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/failFast.pdf)

Comment: I guess that one of the reasons I asked it was that I'm newish to ruby and I didn't realize it was potentially an opinionated question..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a design choice, and I imagine it would have been possible to have `nil` respond with `nil` to methods it doesn't know.

To be consistent, you should define [`respond_to_missing?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-respond_to_missing-3F):

```
class NilObj
  def method_missing(*_)
    nil
  end
  def respond_to_missing?(*_)
    true
  end
end
```

If you did monkey patch `method_missing` like you are suggesting, especially if you also redefine `respond_to_missing?` accordingly, you might get some strange side effects as duck typing requires some introspection and that is typically done by checking if an object respond to something than a particular class.

For instance, the fact that `nil` would respond to `to_ary` would seem to suggest that it is "array-like", when it is not the case.

Some builtin methods will call `respond_to?`, and a few will simply call and rescue `NoMethodError`, so even without the `respond_to_missing?` you could get some strange side effects.

Comment: Actually, `respond_to?` checks for methods that are actually defined in the class hierarchy and will not trigger `method_missing`, so `nil.respond_to? :foo` will still return `false`.

Comment: @coreyward: Expanded my answer to state that some core methods simply go ahead and call methods without relying on `respond_to?`.

Comment: @coreyward see docs [Object#respond_to_missing?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-respond_to_missing-3F)

Comment: Roger that. I hadn't played with that before.

Answer (score 9):

For a far more thorough answer than I could write, please read Reg Braithwaite's [The Hopelessly Egocentric Blog Post](https://github.com/raganwald/homoiconic/blob/master/2009-02-02/hopeless_egocentricity.md#readme)

Short answer: some people think the behavior of your method_missing trick is desirable, but there are pitfalls. Ruby's designer(s) think that behavior is not appropriate by default. Other language designers choose otherwise (eg: Objective-C)